# How to sort an array based on two conditions in python

Tags: python, sorting

I have the following array:

```
[[8, 1], [1, 1], [3, 1], [8, 1], [4, 0], [2, 0]]
```

How to sort the array based on the first value of the element and if second element equal to 1.
I tried the following way,

```
sorted(x,key=lambda x:(x[0] and x[1]==1))
```

But I got this result:

```
[[10, 0], [5, 0], [5, 1], [2, 1], [1, 1], [8, 1]]
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Actually, I want the array to be sorted based on the first element and the elements in x with `x[i][1]` ==1 to be in the last

Comment: It would be useful if you added the expected output as well, the explanation is still somehow unclear,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
x[0] and x[1] == 1
```

This is a logical expression which will either evaluate either as True (if x[0] != 0 and x[1] == 1) or False. So your sort key can only take two possible values.

By my understanding, what you want is:

- all cases where `x[1] == 1` to appear after all the cases where `x[1] != 1`
- subject to above, outputs to be sorted by `x[0]`

You can't do this easily with a one-dimensional key. To understand why, think about the range of possible inputs in between `[-Inf,0]` and `[Inf,0]` and the range between `[-Inf,1]` and `[Inf,1]`.

Each of these ranges is infinitely large in both directions. If you want to sort them with a one-dimensional key, you somehow need to map two double-endedly infinite ranges onto one number line.

This isn't impossible - if you really had to do it that way, there are tricks you could use to make that happen. But it's a very roundabout way to solve the problem.

It's much easier just to use a two-dimensional key. The sort function checks the zero'th position of a tuple first, and only goes to the first position as a tiebreaker. So, because the value of `x[1]` takes priority in the sort order you want, the zeroth entry of the tuple is based on `x[1]` and the first is based on `x[0]`, like this:

```py
x=[[8, 1], [1, 1], [3, 1], [8, 1], [4, 0], [2, 0]]
sorted(x,key=lambda x:(x[1]==1,x[0]))
```

Output:

```
[[2, 0], [4, 0], [1, 1], [3, 1], [8, 1], [8, 1]]
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked after changing the order

Comment: @Tonystark The other important part besides changing the order is that your key is now a tuple, not a single value.

Comment: What is the difference between a tuple and single value while sorting. Also can we add more conditions in the tuple?

Comment: @Tonystark I'll expand on that question in my answer, give me a moment.

Comment: @Tonystark I'm not sure what you're asking about adding more conditions.